# How to set checkbox should be selected based on conditions using angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I have the following code.

**html:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-if="isOwner">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxClicked"  
         />
   </div>
        <span ng-show="checkboxClicked">Non Editable</span> 
        <span ng-hide="checkboxClicked">Editable</span>  
  </body>
```

**js:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isOwner="true";
  $scope.checkboxClicked="true";
});
```

1. If `Owner` and `checkboxClicked` values are `true`, then `checkbox` should be always selected by default on execution i.e with Non-Editable.
   like:

[image]

2. It should execute the same above output by default even though if we refresh the browser also (here also if `Owner` and `checkboxClicked` values are `true`).
3. As a Owner, we can `uncheck` this `checkbox` also, so then output should be with the `Editable checkbox` i.e, like:  Editable.

[image]

Please help me in this context to get my desired outputs as per above screenshots and conditions, I have tried with that code, but it is giving with empty checkbox with Non Editable text, as I believe I am failing to write the conditions.

Created [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OVNxZ0buUVV8hK4I).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with AngularJS when you bind a variable directly to the $scope:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7Nd_me5YrHU

To fix this, you have to create an additional object which wraps the data in the $scope which are available in the template:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    isOwner: false,
    checkboxClicked: false
  };
});
```

And change the template accordingly:

```
<div ng-if="data.isOwner">
  <input 
    type="checkbox"
    ng-model="data.checkboxClicked"/>
</div>
...
```

Comment: @mark, thank you for your reply, but If I do like above your code, always I am getting Editable text only, I am not getting as per my desired output(s). Can you please let me know once.

Comment: @mark, I have edited your post, edited with true instead of false in js, then it is working fine as per my expectation and your explanation as issue with $scope in angualrjs. Thank you very much for your help :-)